# Changing values by condition in Pandas Python, similar to the lookup function in Excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Following dataframe df is given:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['Cash', 'CH0038863350', 'DE0007164600'],
    'Country': ['United States', 'Switzerland', 'Germany'], 'Category': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
```

If value of ISIN is 'Cash' the value of 'Category' shall be changed to 'Cash'. Thus means df will become

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['Cash', 'CH0038863350', 'DE0007164600'],
    'Country': ['United States', 'Switzerland', 'Germany'], 'Category': ['Cash', 'B', 'C']})
```

How to do this?

Comment: `df.loc[df.ISIN.eq('Cash'), 'Category'] = 'Cash'`

Comment: @Psidom Ty, looks great!